# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many relations with two types of Users and one type of Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem related with this association. A pasted code is better than any title:

**table.rb**

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, class_name: 'User'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :managers, class_name: 'User'
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tables
end
```

**migration - join table**

```
class UsersToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tables_users, id: false do |t|
      t.references :user, as: :client
      t.references :user, as: :manager
      t.references :table
    end  
  end
end
```

**Problem**

```
tab = Table.new
tab.save
tab.clients.create
tab.clients.create
tab.clients.create
tab.managers.create

tab.managers.size # == 4
tab.clients.size # == 4
```

When I creating associated Objects(Users) they all are linked to both clients and managers.
I want to be able to create them separately - When creating a client - only number of clients rise, when creating manager, only number of managers rise.
In other words I want this:

```
tab.managers.size # == 1
tab.clients.size # == 3
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Consider using Single Table Inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_and_belongs_to_many :stuff, class_name: 'StuffClass'` is just DSL for:

```
has_many "<inferred_join_table_name>"
has_many :stuff, through: "<inferred_join_table_name>"
```

It seems that since clients and managers are names for `User`s, the inferred join table get's to be "TablesUsers", and that is not right.

Try specifyng the join table for both and using different join tables for each relationship:

```
class Table
  has_many :tables_clients
  has_many :clients, through: :tables_clients

  has_many :tables_managers
  has_many :clients, through: :tables_managers
end

class TablesClients
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :table
end

create_table :tables_clients, id: false do |t|
  t.references :client, index: true
  t.references :table, index: true
end

# and the same for tables_managers
```

Then the user belongs to `Table`s in too different ways:

```
class User
  has_many :client_tables_users, class_name: 'TablesUsers', foreign_key: :client_id
  has_many :tables_as_client, through: :client_tables_users, source: :table

  has_many :managed_tables_users, class_name: 'TablesUsers', foreign_key: :manager_id
  has_many :managed_tables, through: :managed_tables_users, source: :table
end
```

Comment: Thank you! On your example I built similar solution using has_and_belongs_to_many.